# Should I be using enum here?

Tags: java, enums

I have a class called `ColorConstants` which is simply a class that defines a number of `public static final Color` fields used throughout my application - making it easy to change color schemes etc. What I would like to do is have two schemes: inverted, not-inverted. I'd like to set this class up so that the same field names may be references to different colors depending on the scheme / theme. Rather than to check / get the necessary color everytime.

I've never used an `enum` before, and was just wondering if it's suited for this?
Alternatively I'd just make the fields non-final and use a `setAll(int theme)` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use enum here.

I would create a class containing all the color fields (non-final), but without value. And create extending classes that define all the colors in the constructor.

```
public abstract class ColorScheme
{
    public Color background;
    public Color foreground;
    public Color cursor;

}
```

And now create an implementation of the ColorScheme:

```
public class DarkColorScheme extends ColorScheme
{
    public DarkColorScheme()
    {
        background = new Color(0x111111);
        foreground = new Color(0xDDDDDD);
        cursor     = new Color(0xEEEEEE);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use your color schemes like this:

```
public ColorScheme colorScheme = new DarkColorScheme();
```

From now on you can create extra color schemes and simply use in the line above the new colorscheme and everything should work dynamically.

Comment: I really like this approach, but what if I have several color schemes? My original idea was to have an internal switch to determine the scheme and have all the other classes access the colors statically. I could create all the color scheme classes as private classes that would simply switch out the color references rather than redefining each one everytime the scheme changes. I'm rolling with that. Thanks. :)

Comment: I agree. Sure one can use an enum here (you could get by without anything but enums after all), but I think a class really fits better here. Especially considering that this way you can dynamically load new color schemes instead of having a hard coded list - which could come in handy some day.

Comment: @paranoid You have to specify somewhere which color set is used anyhow, so instead of replacing static colors, just replace the current ColorScheme instance with the new one instead.

Comment: @Voo that is what I was trying to say in my comment - makes a lot more sense to do it that way, you're right.

Comment: Nice answer. I was going to write something like this, but you beat me to it. It could possibly be improved by explaining where "new DarkColorScheme()" is best placed, but you wrote this in about 2 minutes.

Comment: @Voo: Exactly what I was thinking. "Loading ColorSchemes from a file will become handy if he continues his project". For your second comment: That is indeed what I mean. Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement this with at least one enum, if not two. One for `ColorScheme`, and possibly another one for `Color`. `ColorScheme` would have (to start) two elements, each of which could "know" about its constituent colors. Loose example:

```
enum ColorScheme {

    NORMAL(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE),
    INVERTED(Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW);

    private final Set<Color> colors;

    public ColorScheme(Color... cs) {
        this.colors = EnumSet.of(cs)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if `Color` is an enum, why an `ArrayList` and not an `EnumSet`?

Comment: Sure, why not? Like I said - just a loose example. I'll edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no `EnumSet.of(E ... e)`... What a mess in that class. Take a look at the JavaDoc and check out the whole bunch of overloads for `of`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Comment: @Martijn you're looking at ancient JavaDocs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#of(E,%20E...)

Comment: But there is still no `EnumSet.of(E ... e)`... And it is still a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the values of an object has nothing to do with the fact that you are using enums or not.

You can achieve the same result by using primitive constants or enums. In my opinion you should use enums becuase that way is more easy to know which constants are available and also you make sure that someone that calls your method does send you only the constants that are defined in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a `ColorScheme` class, which holds the colors used in a single color scheme.
This could be an `enum` if all your schemes are hard-coded. So, for example:

```
public enum ColorScheme {
    NORMAL( Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK ),
    INVERTED( Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE );

    public final Color foreground;
    public final Color background;

    // Note that enum constructors *have* to be private
    private ColorScheme ( Color bg, Color fg ) {
        this.foreground = fg;
        this.background = bg;
    }
}
```

This would define two different color schemes. You can then pass those objects around, and changing the color scheme is just means of changing the referenced object. Adding a third color scheme would also be as simple as adding another constant.

This has the drawback of not being able to extend the number of color schemes at runtime, because `enum`s have a limited number of instances (one per constant). Making it a regular class with constant fields (`public static final`) for the commonly used ones in your code might be a better approach in some circumstances.